# Loop Through Header Tabs Tree MySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, tree, tabs, iteration

Trying to loop through a tree extracted from mysql table to form a well organized header tabs , and i'm doing that because on each tab i can give a permission for a specific user to see this tab or not. 
Table include the tabs details 
Table looks like that :

Table tabs

```
Id        Text         isparent        parentid        hassub
1         Menu 1          1                              1
2         Menu 2          1                              1
150       Menu Level 1                     1             1
151       Menu Level 1.0                   150           1
152       Menu Level 1.00                  151           1
153       Menu Level 1.000                 152           0
154       Menu Level 2                     1             1
157       Menu Level 2.x                   154           0
158       Menu Level 1.x                   150           0
159       Menu Level 1.y                   150           1
160       Menu 2.1                         2             1
161       Menu 2.11                        160           0
163       Menu Level 1.yy                  159           0



 echo '<ul id="main-menu" class="main-menu">';


                $selectparent = "SELECT * FROM tabs WHERE isparent>0";
                $runparent=mysql_query($selectparent,$con);
                if(!$runparent)die("ERROR11");

                for($counterparent=0;$rowparent=mysql_fetch_assoc($runparent);$counterparent++){

                    $parentid=$rowparent['Id'];
                    $parenttext=$rowparent['text'];
                    $parenthassub=$rowparent['hassub'];

                    if($parenthassub==1){       // if parent has sub , select from child tab where parent id =

                        echo '<li class="has-sub">';
                        echo 'text';

                        while($parentid>0){

                            $selectchildparent = "SELECT * FROM tabs 
                                            WHERE parentid='$parentid'";
                            $runchildparent=mysql_query($selectchildparent,$con);
                            if(!$runchildparent)die("ERROR11");
                            echo "<ul>";
                            for($counterchildparent=0;$rowchildparent=mysql_fetch_assoc($runchildparent);$counterchildparent++){

                                $childid=$rowchildparent['Id'];
                                $childhassub=$rowchildparent['hassub'];
                                $childtext=$rowchildparent['text'];

                                if($childhassub==1){    // if child has sub select from childtab where child_id=childid
                                    echo '<li class="has-sub">';
                                    echo 'text';
                                    $parentid=$childid;
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo '<li>';
                                    echo 'text';
                                    echo '</li>';

                                }
                            }
                            $parentid=0;
                            echo "</ul>";
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                                    echo '<li>';
                                    echo 'text';
                                    echo '</li>';
                    }
                }
                echo '</ul>';
```

I need to make it as a header tabs (Tree based) if the tab has sub it will read for the other childs that has same parent id .

Answer (score 1):

Use mysqli statements as mysql statements are deprecated.
Try this,

```
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

echo '<ul id="main-menu" class="main-menu">';
$selectparent = "SELECT * FROM tabs WHERE isparent>0";
$runparent= mysqli_query($con, $selectparent);

$rowparent = mysqli_fetch_all($runparent,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
for($counterparent=0;$counterparent < count($rowparent);$counterparent++){

    $parentid=$rowparent[$counterparent]['Id'];
    $parenttext=$rowparent[$counterparent]['text'];
    $parenthassub=$rowparent[$counterparent]['hassub'];
    echo '<h4>'.$parenttext.'</h4>';
    recursive_loop($con,$parentid,$parenthassub);
}
echo '</ul>';

function recursive_loop($con, $id, $hassub){
    if($hassub == 0)
        return;
    echo '<ul>';
    $selectparent = "SELECT * FROM tabs WHERE parentid = $id";
    $runparent= mysqli_query($con, $selectparent);
    if($runparent){

        $rowparent = mysqli_fetch_all($runparent,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        for($counterparent=0;$counterparent < count($rowparent);$counterparent++){

            $parentid=$rowparent[$counterparent]['Id'];
            $parenttext=$rowparent[$counterparent]['text'];
            $parenthassub=$rowparent[$counterparent]['hassub'];
            echo '<li class="has-sub">';
            echo $parenttext;
            echo'</li>';
            recursive_loop($con,$parentid,$parenthassub);
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

I have used recursion as we dont know how deep your menu is.